# What happens to your class features if you short rest while your form has been changed?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, polymorph, spell-slots, rests

Bob the Warlock has blown all of his spell slots. The friendly party druid casts Animal Forms on Bob, and while in his animal form he takes a Short Rest. After the rest completes, he drops out of animal form for whatever reason. Does Bob have his spell slots back, or does he have to take a rest while in his Warlock form to regain htem?

This kind of situation could also come up with Polymorph ([all](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) [three](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-polymorph) [varieties](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)) or [Shapechange](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange), combined with [Catnap](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/catnap).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Rules Do What They Say

Unless overridden by another rule (specific beats general), spells and features do exactly what they say.

#### With *Polymorph*, You Don't Have The Feature

The *Polymorph* spell description contains the line:

> The target’s game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast.

Class features are part of your statistics.  Which means that at the time of the rest you don't have the Pact Magic feature.  So despite having rested, while you rested you didn't have the feature that allows the slot to recharge.

#### *Shapechange* and Wild Shape Keep Class Features

Both the spell *shapechange* and the druid class feature Wild Shape contain the language:

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the chosen creature, though you retain your alignment and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies [...]
>
> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them, provided that your new form is physically capable of doing so.

So, you'd be able to recharge your spell slots while *shapechange*d or Wild Shaped. Note that the "You retain" is an exception to the normal state of having your statistics replaced.

Comment: +1 I'd also recommend referencing Shapechange or Wild Shape that explicitly call out that they keep class features (in contrast to the others).